# Is it possible to get a list of words given the Lemma in Spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

I am trying to fix grammatical gender in French text and wanted to know if there is a way to get a list of all words from a certain lemma and if it possible to do a lookup in such list?

Comment: Yes Sergey, your solution works perfectly for what I intend to accomplish. Much appreciation :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import spacy
lemma_lookup = spacy.lang.en.LOOKUP

reverse_lemma_lookup = {}

for word,lemma in lemma_lookup.items():
    if not reverse_lemma_lookup.get(lemma):
        reverse_lemma_lookup[lemma] = [word]
    elif word not in reverse_lemma_lookup[lemma]:
        reverse_lemma_lookup[lemma].append(word)

reverse_lemma_lookup["be"]
["'m", 'am', 'are', 'arst', 'been', 'being', 'is', 'm', 'was', 'wass', 'were']
```

Change `spacy.lang.en.LOOKUP` to `spacy.lang.fr.LOOKUP` I guess for French